# Black line under the window title

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

How to get rid of the black color above the grid?

[image: Log in view with a black bar between the title bar and the window content.]

```
<Window x:Class="Nipendo.Desktop.Biur.Login.LoginWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:adorners="http://gu.se/Adorners"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Nipendo Sign Tool" Height="600" Width="600"
    Background="White"
    FlowDirection="{Binding FlowDirection}">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="90"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,15,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="PasswordBox">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#37b0eb"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,15,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type adorners:WatermarkAdorner}">
        <Setter Property="TextStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="15">
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="/Resources/Icons/login_nipendo-logo.png" Height="70" Width="130" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" 
              Grid.Column="1"  
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              Name="comboLanguage" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    </ComboBox>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="350" MaxWidth="450">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SignInTitleText}" 
               FontWeight="Bold" 
               FontSize="25" 
               Margin="0,0,0,15"/>
        <Border>
            <DockPanel>
                <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="/Resources/Icons/login_site.png" Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
                <TextBox Name="txtSiteName" Text="{Binding SiteName}" adorners:Watermark.Text="{Binding SiteNameText}">
                </TextBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
        <Border >
            <DockPanel>
                <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="/Resources/Icons/login_user.png" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                <TextBox Name="txtUserName" Text="{Binding UserName}" adorners:Watermark.Text="{Binding UserNameText}"></TextBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
        <Border >
            <DockPanel>
                <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="/Resources/Icons/login_password.png" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                <PasswordBox Name="txtPassword" PasswordChanged="txtPassword_PasswordChanged" adorners:Watermark.Text="{Binding PasswordText}"></PasswordBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
        <Button Name="btnSubmit" Content="{Binding SignInButtonText}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanSubmit}" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="35">
        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding NeedHelpText}" Foreground="#bcc3c7"/>
    </StackPanel>
    
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBlock FontSize="12">
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding HelpUrl}"  RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding HelpText}"></TextBlock>
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Margin="10,0,10,0">|</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock FontSize="12">
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding SupportEmail}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SupportEmailText}"></TextBlock>
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Margin="10,0,10,0">|</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock FontSize="12">
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding NipendoUrl}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NipendoUrlText}"></TextBlock>
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hard to tell, but why are you setting Grid.Row and Grid.Column on the Grid children, when the Grid does not have any RowDefinitions or ColumnDefinitions? Also be aware the row and column indices start at zero.

Comment: I suspect the xaml you posted is not accurate. The black in your screenshot clearly has rounded corners which is the style you are applying to borders (along with a top margin which is probably your issue), but the border and other margins / rows / columns do not seem to match your screenshot.

Comment: it was a combination of these 2 comments, 10x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Border` style is an *implicit* style that is defined in the `Resources` of your `Window`. If you remove your `Grid` and the other styles, you can see that the issue still persists and is perfectly reproducible, which means the `Window` is the cause. It seems that your implicit style affects the internal style of the `Window` in any way. This is the reason why the bar is black and setting a window background explicitly does not change this color.

If you still need to set the style of the `Border` implicitly, move it to a different inner scope, e.g. down to the next child control, e.g. the `Grid` or just give it an `x:Key` and reference it explicitly where needed.

```
<Grid Margin="15">
   <Grid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Border">
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
         <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2"/>
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,15,0,0"/>
      </Style>
   </Grid.Resources>
   <!-- ...your grid markup. -->
</Grid>
```

Otherwise remove the `Margin` setter completely and add it to the styles of other, specific controls.